# Stats for child components are not always available in User-Timing section of chrome performance tab

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, profiler

Below is the screenshot of my attempt to profile some React app.

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, InspectionPage component is selected, but there is no information about children components displayed in the Bottom-Up tab, like, for example, we can see here - https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/994577100077191168.

What's weird - it's not always the case. Sometimes it's available and sometimes not given seemingly exact same conditions.

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this, as I'm having the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling with this myself, [my answer here](https://www.google.com/intl/en_au/chrome/dev/) is the only definite workaround I've been able to find.

> It appears to be an issue with the current stable release of Chrome. Using a newer version of Chrome, such as [Chrome Dev](https://www.google.com/intl/en_au/chrome/dev/) or Canary, will allow you to use the breakdown until the update makes its way into a stable release of Chrome.
>
> Sources:
>
> - [React Github](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14067)
> - [Associated Chromium Forum Post](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=901418#c1)